# Using WalkDir without saving the directory

Tags: go, file-io, tar

I have a `tar.gz` file that I received via HTTP request. Inside this tar is a folder, which has a file i'm interested in. I am unsure what parameter to give as `root` to `WalkDir`, most attempts end in an `ENOENT` error. My code:

```
func untarFiles(tarBytes io.ReadCloser) (*os.File, error) {
    var dbFile os.File


    gzipReader, err := gzip.NewReader(tarBytes)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    defer gzipReader.Close()

    tarReader := tar.NewReader(gzipReader)

    for {
        header, err := tarReader.Next()

        switch {

        case err == io.EOF:
            break

        case header.FileInfo().IsDir():

            err = filepath.WalkDir(header.Name, func(path string, info fs.DirEntry, err error) error {
                if err != nil {
                    return err
                }

                if info.IsDir() {
                    return nil
                }

                if !strings.HasSuffix(path, "my_suffix") {
                    return nil
                }

                dirFile, err := os.Open(path)
                if err != nil {
                    return err
                }

                defer dirFile.Close()

                dbFile = *dirFile

                return nil
            })
            break
        }
        break
    }

    return &dbFile, nil
```

I've tried `header.Name`, `header.FileInfo().Name()`. Do I have to save this as a temporary directory and delete it later?
Thanks!

Comment: `WalkDir` can only walk the real file system. You could write your own walk function (shouldn't be too hard, [the implementation is very simple](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.5:src/path/filepath/path.go;drc=0a27a458960ffb0adff2f9491eca68c72b79967c;l=443)), or you could unpack it to a temp file and walk it that way.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks. What would be the recommended way? I don't mind saving it on the disk.

Comment: It depends. Unpacking to disk is less code to write but less efficient (it will take longer and use disk). Whether complexity or efficiency is more important, only you can say.